# Reading csv with pandas and it gets NA values

Tags: python, pandas

How can I solve in pandas when I want to read a csv file and it has a NaN somewhere?

it returns:

> ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 22

```
def read_csv_file(filename):
    dtypes = {
        'transaction': int,
        'kev': int,
        'companyName': str,
        'companyOwner': str,
        'companyCountry': str,           
    }

    # Importar el archivo CSV especificando los tipos de datos
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype=dtypes, na_values={'tradedate': -1})
    
    return data.to_dict('records')
```

The problem is that I want to standardize this and I don't know which of all the data types or columns will have that problem

Comment: use `'Int64'` instead of `int`, then you'd have nullable integer dtypes.

Answer (score 0):

For pandas you can use the `.fillna()` method to deal with the NaN values.

If you wanted to fill the NaN in your dataset with 0s,

```
data.fillna(0)
```

There is also `.ffill` and `.bfill` which fills from forward or backward.

And another one worth mentioning is `.interpolate` which by default does linear interpolation for the missing values.

Also try to use a different data type like `Int64`